# magento2: Add my cms static block to the right column in product view

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to put my own static cms block to the column of the right in the product view (to all products).

- I create the CMS block `identifier="first_block"`

here is the my code to:

`app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="first.block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="first_block" xsi:type="string">bla</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

i can't see the new block.

Answer (score 2):

I think your syntax is not correct, please check below syntax to call `CMS` block by `layout.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer If you find it helpful,, you can acceptthis answer by clicking on tick-marking near answer @Muribury